# visual studio - iis7 - setting up?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I have been trying to set up Visual Studio, iis7 and applicationhost.config. It seems like I always leave one thing out or another, sometimes there is access is denied. If it gets past that, then it wouldn't let any db (SQL Server) thing happen ("Cannot open database "testing" requested by the login. The login failed."). Or if iis7 is working, then the site won't run from Visual Studio or vice-versa.

I don't want to give too many rights to too many things thinking "oh it's for testing purpose only". I need to imitate exactly how things would be on production server.

Trial-and-error method has really wasted a lot of time, and I don't think I came across an article that touches all these bases while maintaining safety.  So any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) has an installation called "IIS7 Recommended Settings" which I would suggest you get.  It is a good starting point.